# Create office 365 unified group with the "Office 365 unified API client library"

Tags: office365, office365api

I use the "Office 365 unified API client library" (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph/0.2.8-rc) and I want to create a unified group. I am able to get the token and call the API but I can't get a "unified" group creation to work.

This breaking change seems to be the reason : http://dev.office.com/blogs/Update-On-Office-365-Unified-API

In the property of Group in the "Office 365 unified API client library" there is the property "groupType" but "groupTypes" is missing.

Is there an other way to acheive this with the "Office 365 unified API client library"?

If not does anybody know when the next release of this library is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry about this.  We are in the process of releasing an updated nuget for the Office 365 unified API.  Should be available in the next few days.  Please stay tuned.

Hope this help,

Comment: Approximately when we can expect this library with documentation?

Comment: I believe we'll be making an announcement on the office blogs about our plans for the SDKs and client libraries very soon, so please monitor that blog.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way to do it using the library, but I would recommend using the REST api directly.

With the proliferation of REST apis generally, once you get used to making the calls directly it becomes much easier when you move on to another REST api. Using a different client library for each new REST api makes them much harder to work with.